# Gilbert-Peierls algorithm for LU Decomposition

Tags: algorithm, matlab, matrix

I searched for Gilbert-Peierls algorithm, but I haven't found anything useful (well, I found [this](http://sugandima.wikia.com/wiki/Methods_of_solving_Ax=b_and_their_Matlab_implementations), but it's not working as it should). I think the problem is the second part, and also that those lines:

```
U(1:k, k) = x(1:k);
L(k:N, k) = x(k:N)/U(k, k);
```

should actually be (according to [this](http://sugandima.wikia.com/wiki/Category%3aGilbert-Peierls_algorithm_for_LU_Decomposition) example):

```
U(1:N, k) = x(1:N);
L(k:N, k) = x(k:N)/U(k, k);
```

Also, in that example, L is the identity matrix, which I find a bit strange. Could someone describe the algorithm, please? (with or without code)

Comment: What is k, a vector? If k is a scalar it is strange that L is the unit matrix however the intended code looks like `U(1:k, k) = x(1:k);
L(k:N, k) = x(k:N)/U(1:k, k);` it is not so strange since `A*A^-1 = x*A^-1 = I` I assume that something similar have occured earlier. You do obviously not show all code here, so I cannot say with complete certainity. You should give us more of the code that gives you wrong answer, since the first part of L is gone and if there is a typo in /U(k,k) you should fix it.

Comment: k is a scalar. I put links to the code and the example I found ('this' words). I think it's strange for L to be I because it was supposed to be a lower triangular matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, Gilbert-Peierls’ algorithm is a left-look decomposition and loops one column in every iteration. Thus, the "k" means to loop this column. Note that U is an upper triangular matrixm, so those entries below k in each column are zero. That's the reason of it.

Second, Gilbert-Peierls’ algorithm starts with an identity L matrix is a way to calculate its diagonal entries. It helps users to easily calculate diagonal entries of U at first and then deal with the rest entries of U. That what Gilbert-Peierls algorithm does.

Answer (score 4):

I'm one of the authors of the Gilbert-Peierls algorithm. Here's a link to our original tech report:

https://ecommons.cornell.edu/bitstream/handle/1813/6623/86-783.pdf

It describes the algorithm in detail, though not in Matlab terms.

However, the state of the art has moved on considerably since we wrote this. This article might be a useful starting point:

http://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0895479895291765

I can't find an open copy of this article, unfortunately.

Comment: Dear professor, I have a question, regarding the partial pivoting (PP) in GPLU algorithm: from the introduction of the 1988 paper, it seems that the motivation for the algo is because of the necessity of PP during GE, because dynamic PP alters the none-zero pattern of the matrix, thus a single upfront symbolic analysis (as in Cholesky decomp) is not adequate for general asymmetric matrices. My question is, if, for some reasons (e.g., parallelism considerations), supposed that **the dynamic PP can be omitted**, is there a better algo than "GPLU w/o PP"? Many thanks!

Comment: For sequential settings, you can't do a whole lot better, since you still need to do the same number of arithmetic operations. There are much better parallel algorithms for sparse GE. I haven't kept up with the state of the art, but this paper would be a reasonable starting point: http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn127.pdf

I'm not a professor, though.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the link, Tim!